# Django assertion error when testing file upload on TravisCI

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, file-io, travis-ci

I have an app that allows a user to upload a file and have it displayed on the page. I've created a test class with a method that checks whether a file (stored locally) that is uploaded is the same as the one  that is returned from the POST request. This test works locally, but for some reason, when I run the test on TravisCI, the POST doesn't seem to be returning the file and the build fails.

I think the error is due to the fact that I'm using the python module whitenoise to manage static files in production. Since whitenoise is storing the uploaded files somewhere different than usual, maybe the `django.test.Client.post()` doesn't know where to look for the file. The test was working on TravisCI before I installed whitenoise so this would seem to be the case.

If I leave the whitenoise package in the requirments.txt file to be installed on the TravisCI build server, this scenario happens, but when I try to remove the package from the file, I get the following error, even though I removed the whitenoise settings from the local version of the project settings:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_uploaded_file (photoViewer.test_upload.FileUploadTestClass)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/travis/build/loremIpsum1771/test_ci/photoViewer/test_upload.py", line 16, in test_uploaded_file
    response = c.post('/', {'image': fp})
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.14/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 548, in post
    secure=secure, **extra)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.14/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 350, in post
    secure=secure, **extra)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.14/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 416, in generic
    return self.request(**r)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.14/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 483, in request
    response = self.handler(environ)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.14/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 131, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.14/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 80, in load_middleware
    middleware = import_string(middleware_path)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.14/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 20, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/opt/python/2.7.14/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named whitenoise.middleware
```

**Why is Django still looking for the whitenoise module when it wasn't installed? And how can it be disabled when running locally (on the build server) so that the post request in the test method actually returns the file?**

**test class:**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import os
from django.test import  Client
import unittest

MYDIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)

class FileUploadTestClass(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_uploaded_file(self):
        c = Client()
        originalFilePath = os.path.join(MYDIR, '../live-static/static-root/Keep-Calm-and-Carry-On.jpg')
        with open(originalFilePath, "rb") as fp:
            response = c.post('/', {'image': fp})
            fp.seek(0)
            self.assertEqual( fp.read(),response.content)
```

**local settings file**

```
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    "photoViewer",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]



TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]




# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
 #   '/var/www/static/',
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"live-static","static-root")




MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"live-static","media-root")


CORS_REPLACE_HTTPS_REFERER = False
HOST_SCHEME = "http://"
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER =None
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = None
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = False
SECURE_FRAME_DENY = False
```

Comment: Do you have a different `settings.py` for your tests? According to that stack trace, whitenoise middleware is definitely being loaded. Also, it might not hurt to post your original traceback (before you removed whitenoise). Perhaps we can help you with your original issue as opposed to the one that manifested while you were trying to fix it.

Comment: @MrName My original issue was with deploying to heroku. The app is correctly serving the static files in heroku and I don't think there is another solution for it. This is the settings.py that I'm using for the tests both locally and on the build server

Comment: Got it. When you added whitenoise, did you only add the middleware or did you specifically call it out somewhere else? Like maybe in your `wsgi.py`?